# UIPopoverController in application window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating a `UIPopoverController` from the application delegate and I want to center it on the window, how ca I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the rectangle that it is anchored to when you display it.  Just specify an rectangle and direction that guarantees it will be displayed in the position you want.

It does sound like you may be doing something that would be best done by presenting a custom UIView as a new subview instead of using a popover.  The popover will always have the little arrow coming off the side.

Comment: I'd like to add a subview in my window application, but this view is not responding to the orientation change and i don't know how i can center it in the window, because this view must appear above a UITabBarController in which I have a button with an event, but it responds in the delegate application and is where I have to present that view...

Comment: strictly speaking you can only provide the "popped from" point and the size you want, you should generally allow it to best display itself.  if you want more control you likely want to go about it without a popover controller (per @Dancreek)